# Is there a convenient way to compile two documents at once?

Tags: pdfpages, combine

I have a file `foo.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newcommand{\hello}{Hello world!}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{bar}

This is foo.pdf.
\end{document}
```

The first page of this document is imported using the `pdfpages` package and the pdf is generated by another file `bar.tex`

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\title{Bar.pdf}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This is bar.pdf.

% I want the macro \hello to be passed to this document.
\end{document}
```

The annoying this about this workflow is that altering `bar.pdf` requires that I re-compile `bar.tex`. I'd prefer it if `bar.tex` were automatically compiled every time I complile `foo.tex`. Is this possible? If so, is it possible for this to be done in such a way that passes macros defined by `foo.tex` to `bar.tex`?

I'm aware of a package called `combine`, but reading through the documentation hasn't convinced me that `combine` would solve my problem.

**Update.** The `\write18` command appears to accomplish the task of compiling `bar.tex` when `foo.tex` is compiled.

```
\documentclass{article}

\immediate\write18{latex bar.tex}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newcommand{\hello}{Hello world!}


\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{bar}

This is foo.pdf.
\end{document}
```

However, I'm still not sure how to pass the `\hello` macro to `bar.tex`.

Comment: Have a look at the [latexmk](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) package. I've not ever played with it but I am fairly sure that it can do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use shell-escape to run the second document, this assumes bash syntax in the shell you may need minor changes for other commandlines

bar.tex using `\hello`

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\title{Bar.pdf}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This is bar.pdf.

% I want the macro \hello to be passed to this document.
\hello

\end{document}
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newcommand{\hello}{Hello world!}

\immediate\write18{pdflatex \string\\def\string\\hello{\hello}\string\\input{bar}}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{bar}

This is foo.pdf.
\end{document}
```

[image]